# How to change the value of input without the position of cursor going to the end?

Tags: javascript, input, cursor

**The newest question: can you give another more robust or succinct solution that can exactly accomplish the same goal as I described?**

---

This is the code of mine that has some problems.
I want to split every five letters with a space.

It does well if you enter or delete at the end of the input **BUT** when you enter or delete **NOT** at the end of the input, the cursor would automatically go to the end.

For instance, the textbox now have `ABCDE FGHJK`. If I delete the `A`, the cursor would go the end after deleting the `A`.

```js
let Input = document.createElement("input"); 
Input.setAttribute("type", "text");
Input.style.width = "100%";
Input.style.height = "30px";
Input.style.fontSize = "20px";

// The code AFTER this need modification and improvement

Input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    Input.value = Input.value.replace(/\s*/g,"");
    Input.value = Input.value.replace(/(.{5})/g, '$1 ');
    Input.value = Input.value.trim();
});

// The code BEFORE this need modification and improvement

document.body.appendChild(Input);
```

How to fix the code to prevent it? (It should **ONLY** include original Javascript code but **NOT** CSS, HTML code or Jquery.)

I've tried to relocate the `cursorPosition` but it doesn't work...

I would appreciate that if the code is as **succinct** as possible.

Remember the goal is to **make the input as convenient as possible**.

Some examples here (`|` is the cursor):

| Original Input | Operation | Result Before Operation | Result After Operation | cursorPosSame |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `ABCD|E FGHJ` | Enter `X` | `ABCDX|E FGHJ` | `ABCDX| EFGHJ` | `true` |
| `ABCD|E FGHJK` | Enter `X` | `ABCDX|E FGHJK` | `ABCDX| EFGHJ K` | `true` |
| `ABCDE| FGHJK` | Enter `X` | `ABCDEX| FGHJK` | `ABCDE X|FGHJ K` | `false` |
| `ABCDE |FGHJK` | Enter `X` | `ABCDE X|FGHJK` | `ABCDE X|FGHJ K` | `true` |
| `ABCD|E FGHJK L` | Backspace | `ABC|E FGHJK L` | `ABC|EF GHJKL` | `true` |
| `ABCD|E FGHJK` | Backspace | `ABC|E FGHJK` | `ABC|EF GHJK` | `true` |
| `ABCDE F|GHJK` | Backspace | `ABCDE |GHJK` | `ABCDE |GHJK` | `true` |
| `ABCDE |FGHJK` | Backspace | `ABCDE|FGHJK` | `ABCDE| FGHJK` | `true` |
| `ABCDE| FGHJK` | Backspace | `ABCD| FGHJK` | `ABCD|F GHJK` | `true` |
| `ABC|DE FGHJK` | Enter `Space` | `ABC |DE FGHJK` | `ABC|DE FGHJK` | `false` |

---

Update:

Here is my fix:

```js
let Input = document.createElement("input");
Input.setAttribute("type", "text");
Input.style.width = "100%";
Input.style.height = "30px";
Input.style.fontSize = "20px";
Input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const cursorPosition = Input.selectionStart;
  const imValue = Input.value;
  Input.value = Input.value.replace(/\s*/g,"").replace(/(.{5})/g, '$1 ').trim();
  const lenDiff = Input.value.length - imValue.length;
  if(cursorPosition == imValue.length) {
      Input.setSelectionRange(Input.value.length, Input.value.length);
      return ;
  }
  if(imValue[cursorPosition] === " " && Input.value[cursorPosition - 1] === " ") {
      Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition + 1, cursorPosition + 1);
      return ;
  }
  if(imValue[cursorPosition - 1] === " ") {
      Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition - 1, cursorPosition - 1);
      return ;
  }
  Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
});
document.body.appendChild(Input);
```

**But this fix also has a problem: it cannot deal with copy and paste of multi-letter string (can only deal with single-letter input).**

---

Update:
The problem is solved by splitting the string in the eventlistener `beforeinput`.

```js
let Input = document.createElement("input");
Input.setAttribute("type", "text");
Input.style.width = "100%";
Input.style.height = "30px";
Input.style.fontSize = "20px";
Input.addEventListener("beforeinput", e => {
  if(e.data) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = e.data.replace(/\s*/g,"");
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let cursorPosition = Input.selectionStart;
      Input.value = Input.value.slice(0, cursorPosition) + data[i] + Input.value.slice(cursorPosition);
      Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition + 1, cursorPosition + 1);
      Input.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
    }
  }
});
Input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const cursorPosition = Input.selectionStart;
  const imValue = Input.value;
  Input.value = Input.value.replace(/\s*/g,"").replace(/(.{5})/g, '$1 ').trim();
  const lenDiff = Input.value.length - imValue.length;
  if(cursorPosition == imValue.length) {
      Input.setSelectionRange(Input.value.length, Input.value.length);
      return ;
  }
  if(imValue[cursorPosition] === " " && Input.value[cursorPosition - 1] === " ") {
      Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition + 1, cursorPosition + 1);
      return ;
  }
  if(imValue[cursorPosition - 1] === " ") {
      Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition - 1, cursorPosition - 1);
      return ;
  }
  Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
});
document.body.appendChild(Input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code a bit to restore cursor position:

```js
let Input = document.createElement("input");
Input.setAttribute("type", "text");
Input.style.width = "100%";
Input.style.height = "30px";
Input.style.fontSize = "20px";

function formatValue(value) {
  return value.replace(/\s*/g, "").replace(/(.{5})/g, "$1 ").trim();
}

Input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const cursorPosition = Input.selectionStart;
  const oldValue = Input.value
  Input.value = formatValue(Input.value);

  const newPosition = oldValue.length < Input.value.length ? cursorPosition + 1 : cursorPosition
  Input.setSelectionRange(newPosition, newPosition);
});

Input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  let cursorPosition = Input.selectionStart;
  let value = Input.value;

  if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (cursorPosition === 0) return

    const offset = Input.value[cursorPosition - 1] === ' ' ? 2 : 1;

    value = value.slice(0, cursorPosition - offset) + value.slice(cursorPosition);

    Input.value = formatValue(value);
    Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition - 1, cursorPosition - 1);

  } else if (e.key === 'Delete') {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (cursorPosition >= value.length) return

    const offset = Input.value[cursorPosition] === ' ' ? 2 : 1
    value = value.slice(0, cursorPosition) + value.slice(cursorPosition + offset);

    Input.value = formatValue(value);
    Input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);

  }
});

document.body.appendChild(Input);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but I think there are still some problems... like for example, if I enter `ABCDE FGHJK` and press `backspace` when the cursor is between the `space` and `F`, the `space` or the `E` cannot be deleted. Plus, when I add, for example, an `X` in the middle of `C` and `D`, the cursor jumps to the position after `D` but not `X`.

Comment: But it's better than my tries. @Andrew

Comment: @SundayLi I improved the code a little, so it works more or less as intended. I think now you can easily make small changes to the code if you catch some bugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is much better. Though it still has a little bug, I would accept that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```js
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      const input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute("type", "text");
      input.style.width = "100%";
      input.style.height = "30px";
      input.style.fontSize = "20px";

      let previousValue = "";
      let previousCursorPosition = 0;

      input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        const cursorPosition = input.selectionStart;
        const value = input.value.replace(/\s*/g, "").replace(/(.{5})/g, "$1 ").trim();
        input.value = value;
        input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
        previousValue = value;
        previousCursorPosition = cursorPosition;
      });

      input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        const cursorPosition = input.selectionStart;


        // Handle the scenario when Backspace key is pressed
        if (e.key === "Backspace" && cursorPosition > 0 && input.value[cursorPosition - 1] === " " &&                             input.value[cursorPosition] !== " ") {
          e.preventDefault();
          const valueBeforeCursor = input.value.slice(0, cursorPosition - 2);
          const valueAfterCursor = input.value.slice(cursorPosition - 1);
          input.value = valueBeforeCursor + valueAfterCursor;
          input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition - 1, cursorPosition - 1);
          previousValue = input.value.replace(/\s*/g, "").replace(/(.{5})/g, "$1 ").trim();
          previousCursorPosition = cursorPosition - 1;
        }
      });

      input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 32 && input.selectionStart !== input.selectionEnd) {
          // Space bar pressed with text selected, remove spaces from the selection
          const start = input.selectionStart;
          const end = input.selectionEnd;
          const value = input.value.substring(start, end).replace(/\s/g, "");
          input.value = input.value.substring(0, start) + value + input.value.substring(end);
          input.setSelectionRange(start, start + value.length);
          e.preventDefault();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 32 && input.selectionStart === input.selectionEnd) {
          // Space bar pressed with no text selected, don't add space
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

      document.body.appendChild(input);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions! However, there are still two problems... Still take that example `ABCDE FGHJK`. When you place cursor between `space` and `F` and press `backspace`, the `E` and the `space` cannot be deleted. Another one is that when you place cursor between `E` and `space` and enter an `X`, the cursor will move between `X` and `space`. However it **SHOULD** be after `X`.

Comment: It's better than my tries.

Comment: @SundayLi so meaning, if you put the cursor before F, then press backspace, the E and SPACE should be deleted? what will happen here is that, the characters, will no longer be formatted by 5, since you delete the space, correct me if am wrong.

Comment: here the space is automatically added by regex. So if you press `backspace` between `space` and `F`, the results will be `ABCD|F GHJK`. (`|` represents the cursor here)

Comment: Maybe I can add some examples in the question later.

Comment: @SundayLi , oh thanks for the reference. 

I have here partially working, I belived 2 and 6 item, not working yet.
You can figure out the Process 2 and 6, and let me know if it's working, 


Open my codelink below:
https://codepen.io/bloggersPh/pen/vYVVEVb

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's far better than mine. Though it still has 1 or 2 bugs, I would accept that! Thanks!